# Is "An explanation what is the foundation of this stuff." correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

I was writing my thoughts and put it like that at first:

> An explanation what is the foundation of this stuff. **(&)**

Then I thought: "Wait, shouldn't **is** be at the end?", so I rephrased the sentence and looked at it again:

> An explanation what the foundation of this stuff is. **(#)**

As to a non-native English user, this sentence felt somewhat awkward to me, so I've found an [article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/question-words/what) about it:

> *What as a pronoun*
>   We can use what as a pronoun to mean ‘the thing(s) that’:
>   What we need to do is make a list of useful phone numbers. (the thing we need to do)

And indeed, my sentence can be rephrased using this rule:

> An explanation of the thing that is the foundation of this stuff.

I've also tried to replace **what** by some contextual synonyms:

> An explanation what [inhabits]/[amounts to] the foundation of this stuff.

Or thinking up similar sentence structures:

> I'm analyzing what is there.

But I'm still not sure.
According to my understanding of English, the **(#)** version is totally correct, but after all this research, I'm still not sure about the **(&)** version.

My question - is the **(&)** version correct?

Comment: Neither of the first two sentences are grammatical as far as I can tell. I can't think of any sentence involving *an explanation* ***what*** that makes sense. You can use *an explanation* ***that***, but *what* doesn't work. On the other hand, you could write *an explanation* ***of what*** or *an explanation* ***for what*** but you'd also have to continue it in some form other than what you have in your existing sentences. In short, I don't know what the first two sentences are trying to express. Even if the phrases were correct, they are not complete sentences.

Comment: @JasonBassford, so even with __of__, both of these sentences are not grammatical / appropriate?

Comment: *An explanation of what the foundations of this stuff is* is fine as it stands—but it's not a complete sentence. It's no different than saying *A working theory.* It's formed correctly but it doesn't say anything. There is no verb (or predicate). It would be fine in the specific context of a conversation where it was given as an answer to a question: (*I offer it as* an explanation of what . . .) But as a standalone sentence without that kind of context it's not functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"An explanation what is the foundation of this stuff" is definitely not correct and sounds completely unnatural. As for the second sentence, I would add an "of" or something like that to it.
Also, "foundation" is usually a more formal word, while "stuff" is definitely *not* formal. I would word it like this:

> An explanation **of** what the foundation of this is.
>   An explanation **as to** what the foundation of this is.

Furthermore, this sentence is incomplete. Add in a subject age and verb and you have:

> **I would like** an explanation of what the foundation of this is.